# How can I move address of a label in register

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

In gcc inline assembly for x86, How can I move the address of a label in a register. What it should be instead of $label here, because the assembler is giving error *undefined reference to label*.

Note that the label is outside the *asm* block, that is, within the normal C code.

```
      __asm__ __volatile__ ("movl $label, %eax;");
label:
      .....
```

Comment: What assembler are you using ? gcc inline assembly ? gas ? nasm ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it, the label should also be wrapped in an assembly block, like this...

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("label:");
```

Comment: You can't safely jump between GNU C inline asm statement like this.  Use C labels and `asm goto`.   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Goto-Labels

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
register unsigned long eax __asm__("eax");  // See [1]
eax = &&label;  // See [2]

label:
  // some code
```

However, beware: GCC is free to reorder code under optimization, and so the C `label` may not be exactly where you would it expect it to be.

If you need precise placement of `label` (e.g. because some assembly code will jump to it), you'll be better off coding the whole thing in assembly.

[1] http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html#Local-Reg-Vars

[2] http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

Comment: This probably isn't safe, you need `asm goto` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Goto-Labels.  IDK if that existed in 2011, but it does now.  As you say, it wouldn't be safe for asm code to jump out of an asm statement to `label:` the way you wrote it.  Also, `register long eax asm("eax")` is only guaranteed to work to force an `"r"` constraint to pick `"a"`.  In GCC it does currently do more than the docs guarantee, but usually not clang.